# How to configure testcontainers to leave database container running if a test fails?

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing, testcontainers

When using [Test Containers](https://www.testcontainers.org) the normal behavior is that it will shutdown the container when the test is finished due to pass or failure.

Is there a way to configure test containers so that if a test fails the database container is kept around to help with debugging?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use the reuse feature (in alpha state) of Testcontainers to not shutdown the container after the test.

For this to work you need Testcontainers >= 1.12.3 and opt-in with a properties file `~/.testcontainers.properties`

```
testcontainers.reuse.enable=true
```

Next, declare your container to be reused:

```
static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer()
  .withDatabaseName("test")
  .withUsername("duke")
  .withPassword("s3cret")
  .withReuse(true);
```

and make sure to not use a JUnit 4 or JUnit 5 annotation to manage the lifecycle of your container. Rather use the singleton containers or start them inside `@BeforeEach` for yourself:

static final PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer;

```
static {
  postgreSQLContainer = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer()
    .withDatabaseName("test")
    .withUsername("duke")
    .withPassword("s3cret")
    .withReuse(true);
 
  postgreSQLContainer.start();
}
```

This feature is rather intended to speed up subsequent tests as the containers will be still up- and running but I guess this also fits your use case.

You can find a detailed guide [here](https://rieckpil.de/reuse-containers-with-testcontainers-for-fast-integration-tests/).

Answer (score 2):

The awesome feature for reusable containers also works with JDBC urls, by just adding the query parameter `TC_REUSABLE=true`, like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:8://localhost:3306/dbname?TC_REUSABLE=true
```

You still need to enable the feature by adding the entry `testcontainers.reuse.enable=true` to `~/.testcontainers.properties`.